# Get the size of ARP packet

Tags: c, networking, tcp, ip, arp

I am currently decomposing a data packet into several headers.

Here's my current code :

```
void analyse(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet, int verbose) {


    // Define headers and payload
    const struct ether_header *ethernet = NULL;
    const struct ether_arp *arp = NULL;
    const struct ip *ip = NULL;
    const struct tcphdr *tcp = NULL;
    const char *payload = NULL;

    /* Ethernet header is the first data block of packet **/
    ethernet = ( struct ether_header* ) packet;

    // ARP packet following
    if( ntohs( ethernet->ether_type ) == ETHERTYPE_ARP ) {

        arp = ( struct ether_arp* ) ( packet + ETH_HLEN );

        // If the operation performed by the sender is a reply, we increment the ARP Response Counter
        if( ntohs(arp->ea_hdr.ar_op ) == 2 ) {

            arpResponsesCounter++;

        }

    } else { // IP packet following

        ip = ( struct ip* ) ( packet + ETH_HLEN );

    }

    // ARP header and IP header don't have the same size
    if( arp == NULL ) {

        u_int shift_size = (ip->ip_hl)*4;

    } else {


    }


}
```

According to http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/BSD4.4/newsrc/netinet/ip.h.html and http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/netinet/if_ether.h.html , the size of an IP header is given by `(ip->ip_hl)*4;` but I can't figure out how to get the size of an ARP header.
I need it to define properly the TCP header pointer.

Thanks

Comment: ARP has nothing to do with TCP. You will not find a TCP segment inside an ARP packet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused. The ARP packet *is* the ARP header. ARP is a protocol unto itself, and it doesn't contain other protocols as payloads in its packets the way IP does. It is properly a Link-Layer protocol in the way ICMP is a Network-Layer protocol. Both are top-layer protocols, and neither carries other protocols.

You can determine the size of an ARP packet on a network if you know the size of the layer-2 and layer-3 addresses for the network (48 bits for ethernet and 32 bits for IPv4).

```
Hardware Type is two octets
Protocol Type is two octets
Hardware Address Length is one octet
Protocol Address Length is one octet
Operation is two octets
Sender Hardware Address is Hardware Address Length octets
Sender Protocol Address is Protocol Address Length octets
Destination Hardware Address is Hardware Address Length octets
Destination Protocol Address is Protocol Address Length octets
```

Basically, you have eight octets, plus two times the Hardware Address Length, plus two times the Protocol Address Length.

For IPv4 on ethernet, this means `( 8 + ( 2 * 6 ) + ( 2 * 4 ) ) = 28`.

Comment: All right, but what is the relation between the Ethernet, IP and ARP? Because in this header file http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/netinet/if_ether.h.html there is two defines :
 `#define ETHERTYPE_IP 0x0800  /* IP protocol */`

`#define ETHERTYPE_ARP 0x0806  /* Addr. resolution protocol */`

I am a bit confused

Comment: A layer-2 protocol which needs the layer-2 address of the destination will use ARP to get the layer-2 destination address from the destination host. Ethernet will use ARP to get the destination MAC address, so an ARP packet will be the payload of an ethernet frame. That is where the network stack starts and stops when using ARP.